# Tips and tricks to use Google Apps on Mac OS X

Tags: gmail, google-apps, google-docs

I'm trying to collect advice and utilities to make better use of the Google Apps on OS X, in particular Gmail, Google Calendar and Google Docs.

---

**Gmail**

I tried Mailplane but I find the ratio price/features a bit too high so I decided not to buy it.

Now I use a Fluid's app for Gmail and I installed Google Notifier to have growl like notifications.

---

**Google Calendar**

Idem, Fluid app, and Google notifier.

I'm syncing my google calendars with iCal but it is only one-way.

**Edit**

As @Rene Larsen said, it is possible to use CalDAV to sync with Google Calendar.

I have my own calendar, I shared calendar that I created and I calendar that I  can only view. They appear like that:

[image: iCal Google Calendar sync]

Is it normal that each calendar appear in its own list ?

---

What do you use ? How is it possible to improve that ?

Comment: Syncing google calendars with iCal is two-way in my setup (standard google setup in iCal) - why is it only one-way in your setup ??

Comment: In iCal I subscribed to the .ical link in the sharing settings of my Google calendar, then from iCal I can't "write" an event in that calendar. Does that work for you ?

Comment: @Larsen: Wow ! I'm sooo stupid. I never realized I can add a Google account using CalDav from iCal ... I learned something...

Comment: @Rene Larsen: do you also see the calendars shared by someone else in individual lines (under the title "delegates") ? That's a bit annoying.

Comment: Yes, I can see my other Calendars - and Shared too under the delegates setting on my account i iCal. And they'll then be shown in iCal if I set a check mark next to them.

Comment: And as a side note to the sharing stuff - the way I share a calendar is under "Share with specific people", and then I give it "Make changes AND manage sharing" permissions - and I've then disabled (removed the check mark) "Share this calendar with others".

Comment: If the calendar you are sharing doesn't have write permission then you'll only be able to view it (read only) - which also will be shown in the delegates settings.

Comment: I have write permission on one of my shared calendar, but yet it appears in delegates. It looks like only your own google calandar (the first one) really belongs to you.

Comment: Yes, that's right - delegates isn't 'your' Calendars. If you want to have more 'of your own' Calendars, then create a new under your Google calendar, then they'll be placed next to your main calendar.

Comment: OK, thanks ! One more question: did you manage to create one new "your own" google calendar from iCal ?

Comment: No this is not possible - you can only create local "On My Mac" Calendars with iCal.

Comment: I've just tried to create a new Calendar under my own Google Cal., and it was also shown under "Delegates" - so this means that it will only be the main Calendar that will go on the top level, and all other (shared and your own created) under "Delegates". The one I created my self got Read/Write permissions by default, so it is a two-way. The shared Calendars need to be set to (as I also wrote above) "Make changes AND manage sharing" - otherwise they only become one-way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This tip](http://blog.controlgroup.com/2009/06/30/fusing-google-calendars-with-ical/) describes how to avoid delegates in iCal:

> **STEP 1: disable your delegate calendars from iCal**
>
> 1. Open iCal, then select ‘Preferences’ from the iCal dropdown menu
> 2. Select your Google CalDAV account and open the ‘Delegation’ tab at the top of the window
> 3. Uncheck each checkbox corresponding to each delegate calendar; they will disappear from the main calendar view where they were currently shown as delegates
>
> **STEP 2: create the necessary account(s) for each delegate calendar**
>
> A typical Google Account URL has the following form: https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/USERNAME@gmail.com/user
>
> This should be already present on your existing CalDAV account (the one you expunged the delegates from). Replace ‘USERNAME’ with your Google Account username, then copy and paste the line above into a temporary text document for now.
>
> 1. Open your browser and log in into your Google Account, then follow the Calendar link
> 2. Select ‘Settings’ on the ‘My calendars’ box on the left column of the page
> 3. Select the delegate calendar you want to keep in sync from the main page’s frame
> 4. At the bottom of the next page (the with the selected calendar’s details), copy the Calendar ID value (shown as clear text) which can be found in the ‘Calendar Address’ section; the Calendar ID has the following sample structure: qwertyuiopasdfghjkl1234567@group.calendar.google.com
> 5. Go back to the previous temporary text document where you saved your Google Account URL, paste the Calendar ID value you copied in the previous step and replace the ‘USERNAME@gmail.com’ part as follows (replace the Calendar ID with your correct value):https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/qwertyuiopasdfghjkl1234567@group.calendar.google.com/user
> 6. Then copy the whole resulting string
> 7. Go to iCal, select Preferences once again and add a new CalDAV account: please make sure you expand the ‘Server Option’ dropdown and paste the aforementioned string into the ‘Account URL’ field.
>
> You will need to create a brand new iCal account for each delegate you have set up on Google Calendar. When done, your iCal software will display each delegate(s) as separate calendars, and each one of them will be shown into iTunes and will be available for synchronization in the Device’s Info tab.

Comment: But you still have the Calendars shown separately, so what is the benefit of it ?? If we are talking about shared calendars, then you don't always have the necessarily account informations - which you only have for your own calendars.